# Maple evalf(int) doesn't work for me

Tags: maple

```
evalf(int(Pi^2*exp(-N(cos(phi)+sin(phi))), [N = .1 .. 100, phi = .1 .. (1/2)*Pi]))
```

This result is basically the same expression. It doesn't seem to be trying to calculate it. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a multiplication sign after the **N**. A name immediately followed by a left parenthesis is viewed as function application, not multiplication.

Also, if you know that you want numeric integration rather than symbolic, you should use **Int** rather than **int**. Otherwise it wastes time trying symbolic integration in vain.